# Ordered list showing all zeros in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, html-lists

I have an `<ol>` (ordered list) and in FF, Safari, Chrome it is rendered correctly.  However in IE9 it is showing all zeros.  It is not a spacing/padding issue because I am able to see the zeros.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<ol> 
    <li>Enter basic company information</li> 
    <li>Select from our portfolio of products</li> 
    <li>Attach your employee census</li> 
    <li>Review your selections and submit your request.</li> 
</ol>
```

Anyone run into that problem and hopefully a solution?

[image: ol issues]

Comment: I'd suggest providing the HTML that's causing you trouble - along with any styles that are applied to it (either directly or inherited).

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? Or a code sample?

Comment: btw, ol actually means 'ordered list', thus the numbers before each list item

Comment: <ol>
                <li>Enter basic company information</li>
                <li>Select from our portfolio of products</li>
                <li>Attach your employee census</li>
                <li>Review your selections and submit your request.</li>
            </ol>

Comment: You're going to have to provide a screenshot and some more code including css. I've tested it on IE9 and it's working fine http://jsfiddle.net/rpjrj/

Comment: Are you sure it is a "zero" and not just a circle?  Maybe your CSS has list-style-type:circle; We REALLY need some more HTML and CSS.

Comment: My list-style is decimal outside none.  How do I add a screenshot here?

Comment: @Rkstarcass - Screenshot won't help. IIRC this bug can sometimes occur in Internet Explorer because of improper CSS. Please give us the URL of website where the problem occurs, or use jsfiddle.net to publish your code. http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2006/10/15/internet-explorer-ordered-list-non-incrementing-list-item/ seems to be related to behaviour you are observing.

Comment: I am experiencing the same - but only when I use JQuery to dynamically hide/show divs containing the ordered lists.  Changing list-style did not help.  My CSS is too long to post here.  IE9 in 9 mode and 8 mode.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Update 3/20/2012 - Fixed in IE10

This regression has been fixed in Internet Explorer 10 (all document modes). Microsoft has deleted the **Connect** entry, so you cannot review its status. Since Microsoft now pushes IE10 down automatically, it should be working for all your regular customers.

---

This is a known IE9 regression, which has been reported on Microsoft Connect:

[Ordered list numbering changes from correct to 0, 0](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/657695/ordered-list-numbering-changes-from-correct-to-0-0)

> **Type**:  Bug
>   **ID**:    657695
>   **Opened**:    4/6/2011 12:10:52 PM
>   **Access Restriction**:    Public
>
> **0** Workaround(s)
>   **5** User(s) can reproduce this bug

---

**Update:**

> Posted by **Microsoft** on 6/14/2011 at 3:20 PM
>   Thank you for your feedback.
>
> We were able to reproduce the issue and are investigating it.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The Internet Explorer Team

---

**HTML page that reproduces bug:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>IE9 Ordered List Zero Bug</TITLE>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function ()
        {
            document.getElementById("dv1").innerHTML = "<ol><li>XXX</li><li>YYY</li></ol>";
            var container = document.createElement('span');
            container.style.cssText = "display:none";
            document.getElementById("dv2").appendChild(container);
        }, 1000);
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<DIV id="dv1">
    <OL>
    <LI>AAA</LI>
    <LI>BBB</LI>
    </OL>
</DIV>

<DIV id="dv2"></DIV>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

[A workaround](http://klalex.com/2011/06/broken-ordered-list-in-ie9/) is to place an empty element after your `DIV`:

```
<div id="one">
   <ol>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
   </ol>
</div>
<div id="two" style="display:none">
   <ol>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
   </ol>
</div>
<div id="empty"></div>
```

### Browsers that exhibit the bug

**Internet Explorer 9 (9.0.8112.16421)**

- Document Mode Quirks: Works
- Document Mode IE7 standards: Works
- Document Mode IE8 standards: **Fails**
- Document Mode IE9 standards: **Fails**

**Internet Explorer 8 (8.0.6001.19048)**

- Document Mode Quirks: Works
- Document Mode IE7 standards: Works
- Document Mode IE8 standards: Works

**Internet Explorer 7 (7.0.6000.16982):** Works

**Google Chrome 10 (10.0.648.134):** Works

Comment: page not found when trying to access microsoft connect link (registered).  is there any info on this?  thanks

Comment: The page is (still) there on Microsoft Connect. Updated answer with acknowledgment from MS.

Comment: Damn, doesn't seem to work for me. *Update*: hiding + showing w. delay worked!

Comment: I up-voted but you should of included the JS component in your workaround. ie. call document.getElementById('empty').innerHTML = ' '; after you call your JS show methods.

Comment: @JoshStuart i would include a workaround, but i don't know any.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution :)

1. Show the element:

   ```
        el.show();
   ```
2. Then:

   ```
    setTimeout(function(){
           $("ol").css("counter-reset", "item")
    }, 1);
   ```

Comment: This does not (always?) work. doing a "count-reset" update (sometimes?) fixes one/some of the `<li>` elements but not all of them.

Answer (score 3):

The empty div workaround did not work for me. Here is some simple jQuery that did the trick.

```
// Workaround for IE list display bug
$('ol').hide().delay(1).show();
```

Comment: I found that this works only after a 'show' has completed. For me this was the solution:    setTimeout(function(){$('ol').hide().delay(1).show();}, 2);

Comment: This worked for me. And if you're using an older version of jQuery (without the delay method), you can set the show() function as a callback to execute after the hide() function.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in certain scenarios, specifically those that involve AJAX. This article runs through steps to reproduce but does not give any resolution:

http://blog.darkthread.net/post-2011-03-19-ie9-ol-bug.aspx

Note that the article is in Chinese; I translated it with Chrome.

Here is a **working** fiddle that shows it is possible to dynamically update a list without issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/6tr9p/18/

Unfortunately, this doesn't rectify the problem when there is a need to combine AJAX/IE9/Ordered Lists, which is probably the case if the OP is using SharePoint.

After wasting several hours on this problem myself, I can confirm that (outside of SharePoint) this is definitely a problem on IE 9.0.8112 on Windows 7. It also appears to impact the CSS `counter-increment` methodology for implementing ordered lists as well (i.e. it doesn't work; list items are still all numbered with zero).

I will update my answer if I find a better solution than "deal with it"/"remove AJAX".

EDIT: Here is my "better answer".

**This code has only received preliminary testing, and involves hooking into the AJAX client-side API. It may break in other versions of IE, or in other browsers. Use at your own risk.**

That said, it fixes the behavior of ordered lists displaying all zeros in IE9 with both implicit and explicit start numbers defined (via the start attribute). Note that the start attribute is no longer deprecated in HTML 5.

```
function endRequest_OL_Fix(sender, args) {
    var ols = document.getElementsByTagName("ol");

    for (var i = 0; i < ols.length; i++) 
    {
        var explicitStart = ols[i].start;

        if (explicitStart > 0) {
            ols[i].start = -1;
            ols[i].start = explicitStart;
        }
        else {
            ols[i].start = 1;
        }
    }
}

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequest_OL_Fix);
```

Once a request completes (including an async request) all OL tags on the page are examined. If they have an explicitly defined `start` attribute, it will be preserved, reset, and reassigned. Otherwise, `start` will be explicitly assigned.

This forces a redraw and--with the aforementioned caveats--fixes the problem.

Comment: The bug does not seem to me to have anything at all to do with AJAX. It's just toggling visibility that does it.

Comment: @Pointy - If I recall, I was specifically having trouble when inserting elements into the DOM after an AJAX request so I assumed that it must be dynamic node creation/insertion which caused the issue (which is what my answer tests and attempts to fix). Glad you commented; there is much more information about the problem since I posted my answer. I have since encountered it in another scenarios.

Comment: Well I appreciate your answer because it's the only one on the page that works for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue myself recently and came up with a different solution than including an empty div. Could definitely use more testing in different scenarios but this worked for me, even when the list was hidden and shown again.

```
var ieTimeout;
var selectorWrapperSet = $(selector);

selectorWrapperSet.css("display","none");
ieTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
selectorWrapperSet.css("display","block");
}, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Alex Kleshchevnikov - http://choosedaily.com/2481/ie9-bug-ordered-list-zeroes-ajax-request/

I was using that code; but, I was still getting zero's.  I have modified it to add another OL after the offending one and then hide it shortly afterwards.

"windows_instructions" is the OL that I'm fixing zero's for.  "ie_fix" is the dummy OL I'm hiding.  I tried using 2 ms as the second timeout; but, it wasn't enough time.  Since my ajax content is fading in, I'm not getting a FOUC with 100 ms.

If it's helpful to future fixes, it seems like the issue is always with the last OL on the page.

Here's the code:

```
if($("#windows_instructions").length>0)
    {
        $("#windows_instructions").hide();
        ieTimeout = setTimeout(function() 
        {    
            $("#windows_instructions").show();
        }, 1);
        ieTimeout = setTimeout(function() 
        {    
            $("#ie_fix").hide();
        }, 100);
    }
```

Comment: The empty element after your DIV Workaround did not work for me. In my case the IE 9 ordered list issue appears after an AJAX PostBack adds a new ordered list to the UpdatePanel. Hiding and showing the Div containing the ordered list works great! :)

Answer (score 1):

First, it's possible to see this bug with nothing but CSS. It happens any time an `<ol>` is hidden and shown. [**Example jsfiddle that shows bug.**](http://jsfiddle.net/XpfCc/)

It's also **possible to fix the bug with nothing but CSS** in some circumstances. The fix is consistent, but the code is delicate and not the nicest. Lots of things that *shouldn't* make any difference in CSS do here, so code it carefully. [**Example jsfiddle that works.**](http://jsfiddle.net/XpfCc/7/). The basic idea is: toggling the line instead of the list, then re-creating the list numbering with `counter-reset` on the (visible but sometimes empty) `<ol>` and `counter-increment` on the `<li>`.

Advantage: everything here can be tucked away inside an IE-only stylesheet. If the `:hover` doesn't make sense in your case and you use something like jQuery `.show()`, consider something based on `.addClass()` instead.

Talking of adding classes, as if this bug wasn't strange enough already, it seems that `<ol>`s *work* in IE in conditions like the first example if Javascript adds a class to the wrapper element - even if the class doesn't do anything. [**Here's a jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/XpfCc/11/). Can't guarantee that'll work anywhere else, but it works here.

---

If you're trying to understand the bug, a) good luck, and b) [**take a look at this jsfiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/XpfCc/12/). It's what happens if you do the CSS `counter` option (plus regular numbering), but toggling the `<ol>`s not the `<li>`s. You get the crazy situation where, what's shown is completely different depending on whether you mouse over in from the previous sibling, the next sibling, or neither. Makes no sense... but it's probably a clue as to what on earth this bug really means.

---

I've also got a situation I can't replicate where the numbering is all 1s, all 2s, all 3s etc depending on which `<ol>` it is: the first on the page becomes 1,1,1,1,1, the second becomes 2,2,2,2,2, then 3,3,3,3,3, etc. Can't isolate what causes that quirk.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it looks like you're using SharePoint.  I'm guessing that there is some CSS interference resulting from exisiting CSS settings in SharePoint.

As a test, try declaring your ol style inline and see if it helps.

```
<ol style="list-style-type:decimal;"> 
    <li>Enter basic company information</li> 
    <li>Select from our portfolio of products</li> 
    <li>Attach your employee census</li> 
    <li>Review your selections and submit your request.</li> 
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the following snippet of mark up in your style sheet -

```
ol {list-style:decimal}
```

What this does is declare the type of ordered list you would prefer if you haven't yet declared it in your stylesheet.

Comment: The lack of a default list style does not result in zeros being displayed in Chrome, FF, IE 8 or IE 9: http://jsfiddle.net/jazhx/

Comment: Your right but they might have been ruled by more specified properties.

Comment: possibly. A DOM inspector such as is available with FF, Chrome, IE would be the first place for the OP to look. Although I would question who would define a rule in the first place that would set all OLs to zero.

Answer (score 0):

The numbering issue occurs after revealing a hidden ol element and can be addressed by modifying or adding a class attribute to an element containing the ol element via JavaScript after the ol element has been revealed. The following code does that in a way that doesn't modify existing class attributes in any substantial way, doesn't leave an empty class attribute in the DOM, doesn't require jQuery, and only allows Trident 5.0 browsers (such as IE9) to execute the code:

```
if (/Trident\/5.0/.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // Windows Internet Explorer 9 Bug Fix
    // Official Bug Report: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/657695/ordered-list-numbering-changes-from-correct-to-0-0
    // Bug Fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584500/ordered-list-showing-all-zeros-in-ie9
    if (listContainerElement.hasAttribute("class")) {
        listContainerElement.setAttribute("class", listContainerElement.getAttribute("class"));
    }
    else {
        listContainerElement.setAttribute("class", "");
        listContainerElement.removeAttribute("class");
    }
}
```

The issue can also be addressed by setting the `display` property via JavaScript:

```
listContainerElement.style.setProperty("display", someDisplayPropertyValue);
```

In my case, I was showing and hiding the list by removing and adding an HTML5 `hidden` attribute on an element containing the ol element (with `[hidden] { display: none; }` for IE9 compatibility) rather than directly manipulating the `display` property, so I ran into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with Edge on Windows 10. It was showing 0s next to list items within an  on a mobile menu that opened using a css transition. Felt like I tried a hundred variants of list-style: none; and list-style-type: none; on the ol, its parents and descendants.

Ended up with this to fix it in Edge / IE but not mess with the styling that worked for every other desktop and mobile browser:

```
/*
  Hack for Edge browser. Some things never change...
  This is definitely dirty, hacky and overkill.
  Without this, Edge on windows 10 shows a 0. next to every list item in a mobile menu that is animated with a css transition on our site.
  Using technique for targeting Edge from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201586/how-to-identify-microsoft-edge-browser-via-css
  Answer by KittMedia: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32202953/
*/
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
  .element-im-targeting ol,
  .element-im-targeting ol li,
  .element-im-targeting ol * {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
}
```