# Issue with li in IE

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a div that on hover will change positioning on an image and toggle a div via css. The list uses **upper-alpha** for styling. This CSS works fine in every browser except IE. The issue that I'm having is that in IE, after hovering over the div, it changes to 0. from A, B, C, etc..

Here's an example in jfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/YALdD/

Comment: seems to be another IE bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584500/ordered-list-showing-all-zeros-in-ie9

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in IE 8 + 9. But I also didnt get the mentioned workaround to solve the problem:/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if this works for you, just put the letters in the lists and get rid of the upper-alpha style, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mjgasner/6J6Nf/3

Here's the workaround that is mentioned from the link in the comment above:

http://jsfiddle.net/mjgasner/94tu4/1/

It clearly doesn't work.

AND

IE won't render those as animations, as they are not supported.

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp

You can animate the color change in all browsers (even IE6!) with jQuery UI:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

Comment: Actually... it is. IE doesn't support changing the lists via css, thats why it does that...

Comment: Just thought i'd offer a solution that will solve several problems at once, but i guess thats not appreciated...

Comment: I'd appreciate a proper solution and would be happy to give you a +1 for that.

Comment: Thanks @Christoph and @MikeyG! Do you guys have an idea on how to fix this? And I only have this issue in IE8&9. IE7 accepts it perfectly fine. The reason why I also included the list-style in so many areas is because I don't know how IE is rendering the styling. Normally I should be able to declare the list-style in _bullet-specs li_ and _bullet-specs-toggle li_.

Comment: It doesn't look like you'll be able to use list-style: upper-alpha;... for some reason IE doesn't know to give it the right numbers before loading if it isn't being rendered.

Comment: I'm sorry, if i had a solution, i would post it;)

Comment: @Christoph I'm sure, but instead you bash other suggestions because they're not how you feel the question should be answered...

Comment: I don't generally bash other solutions. I bash wrong answers. It seemed you didn't read the question AND work through the code. This made your answer plain wrong, sry!

Comment: @MikelWard if this works for you, just put the letters in the lists, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mjgasner/6J6Nf/3/

Comment: @Christoph lol, you've offered ABSOULUTELY NOTHING here, if you know enough about this to say that my answer is wrong you could've certainly given your own "expert" opinion by now...

Comment: @MikelWard hey, don't forget to mark an answer so other people can see what worked too

Answer (score -2):

Here is the link to W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp
You can see all browsers supported for certain element.

If you need something else let us know.

What version of IE are you using?

Comment: That's a nice link, but doesn't cover Mikel's issue.