# li's become '0.' in IE when containing div is hidden and redisplayed using jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, html-lists, show-hide

Weird issue where li's become '0.' in IE:

Please view the following jsfiddle in browser of your choice (excluding IE), and then view it in IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/A8Z4k/1/

Steps to replicate:
1. click hide.
2. Click show.

Result: The list items become:

```
0.Test 1   
0.Test 2   
0.Test 3   
0.Test 4
```

So there are 2 div's in play here. One is hidden on load. When the "hide" link is clicked, it hides the div containing the list, and displays the div containing "RAH RAH". And when the "show" link is clicked, the opposite happens, the orginal div is redisplayed containing 0.'s, and the "RAH RAH" div is hidden.

Note: This only happens when there are 2 divs in play, one hidden and the other displayed. If i remove the second div, i can hide and show all day long and the list items will not appear with 0.'s.

What is the work around to this?

Comment: in what version of IE this problem occurs?

Comment: The easiest workaround is to force your friends and clients to stop using IE.

Comment: Interesting - this behavior doesn't happen in IE 7 (using the developer tools to switch to IE 7 standards).  It does happen with IE 8 and IE 9.

Comment: How can you even *use* jsFiddle in IE? Things jump around like mad!

Comment: @Mahan - I am experiencing this in IE9.

Comment: This question is actually a duplicate of [Ordered list showing all zeros in IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584500/ordered-list-showing-all-zeros-in-ie9).

Comment: @EricBrenden looks promising, i'll try to implement it into my jsfiddle. thanks for that.

Comment: then manually make it 1, 2, 3, 4 in the server-side

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution came from: [Ordered list showing all zeros in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584500/ordered-list-showing-all-zeros-in-ie9)

This one worked for me:

1. Show the element:

   ```
    el.show();
   ```
2. Then:

   ```
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("ol").css("counter-reset", "item")
    }, 1);
   ```

Comment: Trivia: `setTimeout` has a minimum time out of 4ms.  Not that it would break, but the js engine will implicitly set it to 4 if it's less than 4.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
 $('#show').click( function() {
    $('#hide-div').css('list-style-type','lower-roman');
    $('#hide-div').show();
    $('#show-another-div-on-top').hide();
```

});

Sorry, I can't test it for you...