# Ordered list is not rendering in Kendo UI Editor inside Jquery UI Tab in IE9

Tags: kendo-ui

Ordered lists show numbers as zeroes in IE9 when placing inside Jquery UI tab.
In all other browsers including(IE7,IE8) working perfectly.
Can any one help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a duplicate of [Ordered list showing all zeros in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584500/ordered-list-showing-all-zeros-in-ie9) (cannot close it down with this reason, unfortunately).

In short, it isn't really a jQuery nor Kendo-UI issue, but a known IE9 thing.