# How to target Microsoft Edge with CSS?

Tags: css, browser-detection, microsoft-edge

I would like to target Edge and have flexbox behave simliar to Firefox 33 / Chrome, [for more detail see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895349/how-can-i-get-ff-33-x-flexbox-behavior-in-ff-34-x).

Can one target Edge in CSS?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201586/how-to-identify-microsoft-edge-browser-by-css

Answer (score 204, accepted):

To target [Edge (version < 79)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge), we can check for `-ms-ime-align` support, Edge being the only Microsoft browser that supports this property:

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
  .selector {
        color: red;
  }
}
```

Or this one-liner (that one works on Edge and all IEs also):

```
_:-ms-lang(x), .selector { color: red; }
```

Further explanation, including variants to support specific versions of Edge, can be found in [this article](https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/css-hacks-for-windows-10-and-spartan-browser-preview/).

For Edge version > 78, since its rendering engine (browser engine) changed to [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)), which is the Chrome's rendering engine, it should behave like Chrome.

Comment: Neither is working for me in Edge 81 on Windows 10. Here's what I'm trying to apply: `.tb-product-loop-wrap.grid-view.shop-columns-3 ul.products li.product {
  width: 30%;
 }`

Comment: @Zade: Edge versions > 44 have switched to use Blink (Chrome's rendering engine) internally. They should behave the same as Chrome.

Comment: should be starting from version 79: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge

Comment: annoyingly, I am on Edge 91 and its rendering an SVG 1px different to Chrome on the same machine....