# How do I change the CSS style for background-attachment: for Internet Explorer Edge only

Tags: css, internet-explorer, stylesheet

My stylesheet currently uses a fixed background image which works great in all browsers except IE. How do I disable the fixed background ONLY in Internet Explorer Edge? The more specific, the better as I have no idea how the @supports work.

Comment: I should add that I want to change **background-attachment: fixed** to **background-attachment: scroll** in IE Edge only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to target only IE (any version) within a stylesheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417056/how-to-target-only-ie-any-version-within-a-stylesheet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer here for targetting IE edge: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32202953.

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
.selector {
    property: value;
    }
}
```