# Targeting Microsoft Edge With CSS and A Certain Width

Tags: css, media-queries, microsoft-edge

How do you target Microsoft Edge whilst also targeting a width through media query?

I tried nesting:

```
@media (min-width:1700px) {
    @supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
       .grid-image {
           width: calc(100% / 7);
       }​
   }
}
```

and some other weird stuff like

```
@media (min-width:1700px) and (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
    .grid-image {
        width: calc(100% / 7);
    }​
}
```

and nothing works. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: This is a non standard feature and probably shouldn't be used as it may react different among the various browsers.

Comment: You should not target specific browsers. Instead, write for basic implementation across all required browsers and then implement nicer/newer features for the browsers that happen to support them as a form of progressive enhancement.

Comment: calc works perfectly in every other browser. I have a grid of pictures that I want to span the entire screen. IE rounds off to a higher value and causes the last image in the row to wrap over to the next row. Such a bad browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge just recently switched to a Chromium based browser (in 2019) and will now behavior much more as expected.  <s>The calc() function now rounds decimals properly, which will save a lot of headache in the future.</s>  That being said, you still will need target older version for the next couple of years, for people who don't update the browsers as often.

Use this to target IE10/Edge+ pre-chromium base with widths set:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none) and (min-width : 1700px),
(-ms-high-contrast: active) and (min-width : 1700px) {
}
```

Another option is to use JavasScript to add classes.

The example below is old... will update once I can find another older PC to test on some more... the switch to chrome is making me update some of my code as well.

```
navigator.browser=function(){var e=navigator.appName;var t=navigator.userAgent;var n;var r=t.match(/(edge|opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);if(r&&(n=t.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!=null){r[2]=n[1]}if(r){r={name:r[1].toLowerCase(),versionExt:r[2]}}else{r={name:e.toLowerCase(),versionExt:navigator.appVersion}}var i=r.versionExt.split(".");r.version=parseInt(i[0]);if(typeof i[1]=="string"&&i[1].match(/^[\d]+$/i)!=null){r.sub=parseInt(i[1]);r.subversion=parseFloat(r.version+"."+r.sub)}return r}()
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (/edge/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
      var pos = ua.indexOf('edge/');
      var version = ua.substr(pos + 5);
      var parts = version.split(".");
      var mainVersion = parts[0];
      $('html').addClass('edge');
      $('html').addClass('edge-' + mainVersion);
      if (navigator.browser.name == 'netscape') {
        $('html').addClass('edge-pre-chromium');
      }
      else {
        $('html').addClass('edge-chromium');
      }
    }       
    else if (/windows/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && navigator.browser.name == 'netscape') {
      $('html').addClass('edge');
      $('html').addClass('edge-pre-chromium');
    }       
});
```

Hope that helps. I know this is a bit old, but hopefully can help some others in the future.

## UPDATE

The calc() function is still rounding up in the Chromium version, sadly. The JavaScript above seems to be detecting the different version correctly.

Pure CSS target of IE12+.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1700px) {
  _:-ms-lang(x), _:-webkit-full-screen, .selector { property:value; }
}
```

Credit for the above goes to: [How to Identify Microsoft Edge browser via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201586/how-to-identify-microsoft-edge-browser-via-css/32202953)