# Transform scale css working different on Chrome and Microsoft Edge When Printing

Tags: css, scale, microsoft-edge, css-transforms

I am using the css rule "transform: scale()" to scale a flowchart in a website.

The problem happens in the printing result

Everything is working properly in different browsers, Chrome included, but Microsoft Edge scales the chart in a bigger size so it doesn't fit the size I need. I would like to use just one declaration for all browsers.

```
@media print{
    .class-to-scale{
       transform: scale(0.85)
    }
}
```

But in Microsoft Edge it works the same way than Chrome but just if I scale using a lower factor, 0.65 instead of 0.85.

How could I approach this problem to set a different scale for Microsoft Edge.

Thanks.

Comment: For 'normal' ```div``` it seems to be identical in both browsers when scaling down: https://jsfiddle.net/n7xfuscm/1/. To target via ```CSS``` Edge browser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201586/how-to-identify-microsoft-edge-browser-via-css

Comment: i check with different scale factor, in chrome and Edge div transformed in same size

Comment: Thank you both. I forgot to say that it happens in the printing result. I updated the question. I checked that in the browser the scale is the same, but when I go print the page, the result is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it happens to someone, the problem was that I hadn't set the @page size, so I imagine that every browser was taking a different one by default.

I added the next line to my css

```
@page {size: portrait}
```

and now the result of the printing is exactly the same.